# Get records in date ranges

Tags: mysql

I need the records between two date ranges

I have below records in mysql table

```
**id  start_date  End_date**
1   2016-04-11  2016-04-18
2   2016-04-19  2016-04-19
3   2016-04-20  2016-04-21
4   2016-04-22  2016-04-29
5   2016-05-01  2016-05-01
6   2016-05-08  2016-05-10
```

I will provide input as 
2016-04-18 and 2016-04-24

My input values does not points to start and end date. It points to range of dates.My output should contain records with data range from (2016-04-18 to 2016-04-24,both start and end date)

It should provide the output as below

```
**id  start_date  End_date**
1   2016-04-11  2016-04-18
2   2016-04-19  2016-04-19
3   2016-04-20  2016-04-21
4   2016-04-22  2016-04-29
```

First record is <= 2016-04-18 So I need this

Second record is < 2016-04-24 So I need this

Third record is < 2016-04-24 So I need this

Fourth record is <2016-04-24 So I need this

Comment: Please check your query again and correct it or elaborate as there is no date "2016-04-24" in your table.

Comment: The query should get all the records which are in between the date ranges in both ends(start and end date)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SET @start = '2016-04-18';
SET @end = '2016-04-24';

SELECT id, start_date, end_date
FROM mytable
WHERE end_date >= @start AND start_date <= @end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But query should check the start and end date in both column

Comment: @ManiMuthuPandi: Query will check both columns as per given condition, so check with various scenarios at your end to make sure if you are getting desired results...+1 from my side.

Comment: @ManiMuthuPandi If you need to check for overlapping intervals, then this is the standard procedure. If not, then please explain in more detail how you arrive at the expected result.

Comment: @Giorgos Betsos, Zafar Malik, Giorgos Betsos : Initially Misunderstood, When I run in the query it provide as I expected. Thanks for the answer also for your explanations. Thanks a lot.